# mongodb find all records with subdocument id equals to

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

i have the following collection records:

```
> db.products.find(ObjectId("53a9a6aad901f2961403fc9b")).pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a9a6aad901f2961403fc9b"),
    "code" : "N39",
    "name" : {
        "en-UK" : "N39"
    },
    "weight" : [
        90
    ],
    "collectionId" : ObjectId("53a9a6a8d901f2961403fbe2"),
    "fabric_composition" : [
        {
            "fabricId" : ObjectId("53a9a6a9d901f2961403fc69"),
            "value" : 70
        }
        {
            "fabricId" : ObjectId("53a9a6a9d901f2961403fc6a"),
            "value" : 30
        }
    ],
    "visible" : "true",
    "manufacturer" : "53a859d9d901f2e8f81ac83b"
}
```

and

```
> db.fabric.find().pretty()
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a9a6a9d901f2961403fc69"),
    "name" : [
        {
            "en-UK" : "Recycled Organic Cotton"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a9a6a9d901f2961403fc6a"),
    "name" : [
        {
            "en-UK" : "Recycled Polyester"
        }
    ]
}
```

how do i query the mongodb collection `products` to list all products that have a fabric_composition with `ObjectId` for `Recycled Organic Cotton` as an example?

any advice much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use use [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#equality-match-on-fields-within-an-embedded-document) to query subdocuments:

```
db.products.find({
    "fabric_composition.fabricId" : ObjectId("53a9a6a9d901f2961403fc69")
});
```

This query will return all documents that have at least one sub-document with `fabricId` you're looking for.